# Not equal list<> in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

I have 4 tables as follows:

Table 1 Location A

```
 public class CustmLocationA  
 {
     public int Location1_ID { get; set; }
     public string Location1 { get; set; }
     public string Location1_Descrip { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
 }
```

Table 2 location B

```
 public class CustmLocationB
 {
     public int Location2_ID { get; set; }
     public string Location2 { get; set; }
     public string Location2_Descrip { get; set; }
     public int Location1_ID { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
 }
```

Table 3 Location C

```
 public class CustmLocationC 
 {
     public int Location3_ID { get; set; }
     public string Location3 { get; set; }
     public string Location3_Descrip { get; set; }
     public int Location2_ID { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }

     //Location B data
     public string Location2 { get; set; }

     [NotMapped] 
     public bool LocBIsActive { get; set; }

     //location A data
     [NotMapped] 
     public int Location1_ID { get; set; }

     [NotMapped] 
     public string Location1 { get; set; }

     [NotMapped] 
     public bool LocAIsActive { get; set; }

     [NotMapped] 
     public string LocAandB { get; set; }
 }
```

Table 4:

```
 public class CustmContact
 {
     public int contactID { get; set; }
     public int Location3_ID { get; set; }
     public int UserID { get; set; }
     public bool Notify { get; set; }
     public bool Access { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     public string UserName { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     public string LocationAll { get; set; }
 }
```

**What I have tried:**

I am trying to select all locations C with related tables information in locations A and B tables after that I need to select the selected user locations in table Contact (4th table) after that I need to remove all selected user locations from selected locations but I found that cannot be applied to operands of type int and list of  in this line

```
(a.Location3_ID != (from z in db.contacts where z.UserID == UserID select z.Location3_ID))



 //Get Un-selected location by user ID

 public List GetSelectedLocByUID (int UserID = 0)
 {


 var data = (from LocC in db.locationsC

 join LocB in db.locationsB on LocC.Location2_ID equals LocB.Location2_ID

 join LocA in db.locationsA on LocB.Location1_ID equals LocA.Location1_ID

 select new CustmLocationC
 {

 Location1_ID = LocA.Location1_ID,

 Location1 = LocA.Location1,

 LocAIsActive = LocA.IsActive,

 Location2_ID = LocB.Location2_ID,

 Location2 = LocB.Location2,

 LocBIsActive = LocB.IsActive,

 Location3_ID = LocC.Location3_ID,

 Location3 = LocC.Location3,

 Location3_Descrip = LocC.Location3_Descrip,

 LocAandB = LocA.Location1 + "-" + LocB.Location2,

 IsActive = LocC.IsActive

 }).Where(a => a.LocAIsActive == true && a.LocBIsActive == true && a.IsActive == true 


 && **a.Location3_ID != (from z in db.contacts where z.UserID == UserID select z.Location3_ID)**


 ).OrderBy(a => a.Location1).ToList();


 return (data);
 }
```

Comment: You need to format your code in your post so it is easier to read.

Comment: sorry I did not know that :) but I think marc did it thank you marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(answer by Bryian Tan)

The current logic "a.Location3_ID != (from z in db.contacts where z.UserID == UserID select z.Location3_ID)" is trying to compare ONE location with ONE or MANY location. Which will not work, like saying if 1 apple equals to 1 or more apple.

Based on what I posted here

```
//store the list of Location3_ID for a user in a list
List<int> loc3s = (from z in db.contacts
                               where z.UserID == UserID 
                               select z.Location3_ID).ToList();
//then replace a.Location3_ID != (from z in db.contacts where z.UserID == UserID select z.Location3_ID) with below
//return all the result where Location3_ID not belong to the user
!loc3s.Contains(a.Location3_ID )
```